# How to stop new debian stretch installation from upgrade to buster?

Tags: debian-installer

I have searched online and all I can get is how to upgrade the dist. However, what I want to is stay with the dist that I am happy with.

I have made a custom debian installation DVD using simple-cdd. And I check the DVD ISO and confirmed it contains stretch dist on it. However, after I install the DVD, the system is buster, which means the installer automatically upgrades the dist without my consent.

Is there anyway to stop this? Anything that I can do in the preseed file?

Here is the relevant part of my preseed file on the DVD

```
### Mirror settings
# If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.
d-i mirror/protocol string http
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 192.168.0.10
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian/
d-i mirror/http/proxy string

# Suite to install.
d-i mirror/suite string stretch
# Suite to use for loading installer components (optional).
#d-i mirror/udeb/suite string stretch

### Apt setup
# You can choose to install non-free and contrib software.
d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean true
d-i apt-setup/contrib boolean true
# Uncomment this if you don't want to use a network mirror.
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
# Select which update services to use; define the mirrors to be used.
# Values shown below are the normal defaults.
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect
#d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.debian.org

# Additional repositories, local[0-9] available
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string \
   http://debian.myserver.com/debian stable main
```

Comment: Are the sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` using `stretch` of `stable`?

Comment: I have re-edit my question to include my preseed file on the DVD. Does the "stable" keyword in the additional repositories line causes me trouble?

Comment: Yes it is. Now the stable release is buster